# MySQL rand() ignore duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, random, distinct

I have been trying to use the following MySQL:

```
  SELECT distinct(photos.id)
       , photos.file
       , photos.tags
       , photos.desc
       , photos.ratio
       , tags.bid
       , tags.tagname_id 
    FROM photos
       , tags 
   WHERE photos.trending=1 
     AND tags.pid=photos.id
ORDER BY RAND() 
   LIMIT 10
```

I tried using `DISTINCT` to prevent duplicate entries but it doesn't seem to be working in my situation.

What is the best way to get this to work?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? **ALWAYS** explain the desired results, because it's not obvious from *incorrect* query

Comment: `DISTINCT` cannot be used on just one column like that, it sets distinct to all columns you choose, and since I imagine none of your rows have all identical columns you will get all rows.

Comment: I have heard it suggested that instead of using `ORDER BY RAND` a much better method is to perform a sample-probe on an indexed column with known bounds and a dense fill ..

Comment: My problem is basically that if I just use ORDER BY RAND() then I get duplicate values.  I have seen DISTINCT remove those duplicates but it's only when one column (usually ID) is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT photos.id
   , photos.file
   , photos.tags
   , photos.desc
   , photos.ratio
   , tags.bid
   , tags.tagname_id 
FROM photos
   , tags 
WHERE photos.trending=1 
 AND tags.pid=photos.id
GROUP BY photos.id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```

This is the correct way to do your query, but it will arbitrarily choose one row from the photos.id that are the same so you may end up with different results on different instances.

MS SQL valid query, look at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d121/3):

```
select photos.col1,max(photos.col2),max(photos.col3),max(tags.col5),max(tags.col6)
from photos,tags
where photos.col1=tags.col4
group by col1
```

SQL instructions are: when using group by a column cannot be included in select unless it is grouped by OR it is used in aggregate function.

Comment: How about also rewrite for the OP with an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: selecting `photos.file` etc. without using an aggregate function and without grouping on it is evil. Sure... it's valid in MySQL, but it shouldn't be. And it's invalid everywhere else. I second the vote for an inner join.

Comment: @mdahlman Since it is a mysql question is there any need to overcomplicate the query, when as you say, it is indeed valid? I don't see why it shouldn't be valid, as long as the user knows that the selection of rows will be arbitrary then it makes sense to be able to do it, why not just group by one column and then choose a random row from them if that is what the user wants? Seems to me on the contrary to be ridiculous to limit this ability. But anyway, I've added a query that is valid in ms sql, no left join needed.

Comment: @AdrianCornish See above comment.

Comment: Why don't you look at the explain results of each and see which is more efficient and learn which queries the MySQL engine optimizes better than others

Comment: @AdrianCornish I'm genuinely asking for your know-how on the subject. You suggest doing the query with an inner join but provide no reason why this would be better. From what I can see the explain results for inner join with group by, group by without aggregation, group by with aggregation all produce the same explain results, and I can't see a simple way to do the query just using distinct. I made the effort to provide a sql valid query so any suggestions on what a better query should look like would be great. If performance does turn out to be the same would you still think it is 'wrong'?

Comment: @mrmryb You're saying your query is good enough. I agree. It solves the problem; it's good. But the query using agg functions seems at least equally good in all respects (same result set, same performance, etc.) and better in some respects (clarity, portability).